# Using Autofac to switch a concrete implemetation of an abstract factory

Tags: c#, design-patterns, autofac, factory

I am humbling with a problem related to AutoFac and the the abstract factory pattern. My Example is a a service to use an IRepositoryFactory to create a Repository based on JSON or InMemory related to the user input.

```
// Abstract Factory
public interface IRepositoryFactory{
    IRepository Create(string databaseIdentifier);
}

// JSON
public class JsonRepositoryFactory{
    public IRepository Create(string databaseIdentifier){
        return new JsonRepository(databaseIdentifier); 
    }
}

// InMemory
public class MemoryRepository{
    public IRepository Create(string databaseIdentifier){
        return new MemoryRepository(databaseIdentifier);
    }
}
```

The Service should pull the Factory by Constructor Injection.

```
public interface IShopService{
     public string Name {get;}
} 

public class BeerShop : IShopService {
     public string Name {get; private set;}
     private readonly IRepository _repository;

     public BeerShop(IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory){
         Name = "beershop";
         _repository = repositoryFactory.Create(Name);
     } 
}
```

So far I am good with this. But the initialization is not my favorite.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var userInput = ReadInput();

if(userInput = "json")
    builder.RegisterType<IRepositoryFactory>().As<JsonRepositoryFactory>();
else
    builder.RegisterType<IRepositoryFactory>().As<MemoryRepositoryFactory>();

builder.RegisterType<IShopService>.As<BeerShop>();

var container = builder.build();

[...]    

var service = container.Resolve<IShoptService>();
// and so on ...
```

Is this the right approach to solve it? I am not convinced by my own design because it forces the user input before the initialization of the container. What if the user has to change the Repository while runtime? Is the abstract factory pattern the right tool to solve this problem?

Comment: Your `BeerShop` is doing too much: [injection constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). If you move the call to `factory.Create` out of the constructor into the Composition Root, you don't require this factory abstraction anymore. Also note that [factory abstractions are a code smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100).

Comment: I agree Steven. Your client (which is BeerShop) it doesn't look like will use same code/logic for another thing eg:colashoop. Also don't use factory, if you don't have any other chance. Because factory brings complexity.
It looks like, you need this seperation on lower level. You repository will be same but it will use json or memory as Db. Changing db at runtime is very dangerous. You will write something to json and read from memory by user input at same runtime???

Answer (score 1):

Since the type of repository is known at the time the container is configured, you should register the specific repository directly. There is no need to introduce a factory, as there [hardly ever is a reason](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100) to introduce a factory abstraction.

Example:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var userInput = ReadInput();

if(userInput = "json")
    builder.Register<IRepository>(c => new JsonRepository("dbidentifier"));
else
    builder.Register<IRepository>(c => new MemoryRepository());

builder.RegisterType<BeerShop>.As<IShopService>();

var container = builder.build();

[...]    

var service = container.Resolve<IShopService>();
```

This code allows the `BeerShop` to be simplified, because [its constructor would be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) and it now it only depends on `IRepository` instead of `IRepositoryFactory` and `IRepository`. This simplifies testing and makes it easier to reason about this class. Furthermore, it removes the unneeded abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the behaviour of the factory during runtime, then you have to move the logic of deciding the type of `IRepository` being created to the factory itself. You can adapt the pattern and tweak it to fit your requirements rather than conforming to the specific way of doing it.

The following is a way to do it, if you think about it, you can find different ways of adapting it.

```
    public interface IRepository
    {
        //repository contracts
    }

    public interface IRepositoryFactory
    {
        IRepository Create(string arguments);
    }

    public interface IRepositoryBuilder
    {
        RepositoryType Type { get; }
        IRepository Create(string args);
    }

    public class ApplicationSettings
    {
        public RepositoryType RepositoryType { get; set; }
    }

    public enum RepositoryType { Json, Text }

    // Default implementation of repository factory based on applicationsettings.
    public class ConfigurableRepositoryBuilder:IRepositoryFactory
    {
        private readonly ApplicationSettings _settings;
        private readonly IEnumerable<IRepositoryBuilder> _repositoryBuilders;

        public ConfigurableRepositoryBuilder(ApplicationSettings settings, IEnumerable<IRepositoryBuilder> repositoryBuilders)
        {
            _settings = settings;
            _repositoryBuilders = repositoryBuilders;
        }

        public IRepository Create(string arguments)
        {
            var builder = _repositoryBuilders.First(x => x.Type == _settings.RepositoryType);
            //configure builder settings and then call create
            return builder.Create(arguments);
        }
    }
```

Now you can change the global settings anytime and you will get new type of repository from the next call onwards. Instead of a global singleton, you can read from app.config or other settings file also.

You now want to implement the `IRepositoryBuilder` for each type of supported `IRepository` Type